# Sorting polytonic Greek list by initial letter case in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I'd like to extract all the capitalised words from a list of polytonic Greek words. For example, out of...

```
Ἀθηναῖοι
αἱ
ἄλλα
```

I'd like just `Ἀθηναῖοι` as it begins with a capital. I've done this before with a list of words in Latin characters using `=CODE(LEFT(A1,1))` and then sorting by the outcoming number, but this just returns 63 for all my Greek words.

Comment: Are these values in seperate cells? Can you show a screenshot of your data and expected result as a reference?

Comment: Also, look into `UNICODE` function instead of `CODE` to include non-ascii characters. Otherwise these characters are seen as a questionmark, hence `63`.

Comment: Yes in separate cells. UNICODE has solved it. Many thanks!